# dependency property of some sorts in Android usercontrol using MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Android, MvvmCross

Making a custom control derived from LinearLayout.
This control has some properties that might change due to user interaction.
These properties are bound to a ViewModel

```
public class MyControl: LinearLayout
{
    ..Constructors..

    public int Selected
    { 
        get {....}
        set {....}
    }
}
```

How do I implement a notification back to the viewmodel the 'Selected' property value has changed?

*In WPF I would use a dependency property

**INotifyPropertyChanged should also work, however since this control already derives from LinearLayout, it cannot also derive from MvxNotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MvvmCross uses the convention that allows you to link a property `Foo` with an `event EventHandler FooChanged`

If you follow that convention then the two-way binding should just work.

```
public int Selected
{ 
    get {....}
    set {....}
}

public event EventHandler SelectedChanged;
```

If you can't follow that convention - e.g. if you need to use `EventHandler<T>` or if you need to use a different event name - then you'll need to implement a custom binding.

---

For more on this topic, and on Custom bindings too, see N=28 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/

Comment: As so often, Stuart answers the question before the virtual ink has dried. Thanks!